# How to set images and text in toolbar from fragment activities in android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I need to set one imageView and Textview on the right side of toolbar in the navigationDrawer activity.But the thing is that the values for imageview and textviews are different for each fragment activity. And also I need to make the toolbar transparent.I am using default navigation drawer activity.Can anyone help? Any help will be appreciated.

app_bar_main.xml file

```
<? xml version = "1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.unitybees.photo.MainActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            android:background="@null">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageView android:id="@+id/right_icon"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"/>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/right_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:textColor="#000000"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    public static final int right_image = 1;
    public static final int right_texts = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.right_text);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer,
                toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)
                findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        this.setTitle("");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        displaySelectedScreen(item.getItemId());
        return true;
    }

    private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId) {
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (itemId) {
            case R.id.nav_menu1:
                fragment = new Book_now();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_menu2:
                fragment = new Payment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_menu3:
                fragment = new Account();
                break;
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransactionft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
}
```

my Account.java

```
public class Account extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    TextView txt;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.account, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle("");
    }
}
```

Comment: what have you done so far to achieve this?

Comment: sir, i have edited my question . please have a look

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android see if this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Try this if it may help

**1) Put this method in your activity**

```
public void initToolBar(String title) {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(title);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicking the toolbar!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        );
    }
```

**2) To update the method from your fragment call mehtod using**

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).initToolBar("Fragment Title");
```

Comment: yep try it and tell if you need more help

Comment: it works :). and i have one more qstn that how can i set the image size. And also i need to add the image and text on the right side of toolbar.and i need to remove that 3 dots on the right side from the toolbar. can u help me?

Comment: to remove three dots requires you need to handle onCrateOptionsMenu Method.

Comment: what should i do there?

Comment: well ask another question for that and tag me there as i can't paste entire code in comment box here

Comment: I asked another question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44234410/how-to-remove-three-dots-from-the-toolbar-of-navigation-drawer]